# Write a figure to a file automatically in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, eps

Does anyone know if it's possible to automatically write a figure out to a .eps file in MATLAB?

I'm running a script that produces a large number of graphs, and it'd be nice if I didn't have to manually save each one!

Comment: Perhaps related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478414/saving-a-plot-as-a-png-in-matlab).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[print function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) does that:

> Print figure or save to specific file format...
>
> `print(filename,formattype)` saves the current figure to a file using the specified file format, such as `print('BarPlot','-dpng')`. If the file name does not include an extension, then print appends the appropriate one.
>
> `print(filename,formattype,formatoptions)` specifies additional options that are available for some formats.
>
> `print` prints the current figure to the default printer...

Comment: Thanks, saves me a lot of effort =]

Answer (score 10):

print or saveas will do the trick.

```
saveas(fig_handle, 'filename','eps')
print('-deps',fig_handle)
print -deps 1
```

If you want to specify the output file name, you're better off using saveas.

Comment: actually, you can specify the filename just fine with -print -epsc filename

Answer (score 3):

This was answered in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575475/how-can-i-save-an-altered-image-in-matlab), using the [PRINT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) command. Although that question dealt with making .tiff images, it should be straightforward to modify the code given in those answers to write a .eps.

Comment: I'm not loading an image in or out, this is a set of automatically generated graphs, so I'm not sure the same syntax applies.

Comment: Although the text of the question just shows IMREAD and IMWRITE, some of the answers show how to use the PRINT function to output a plotted image.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, you are generating N numbers of figures in a loop, then you should try the command line:

`saveas(gca,sprintf('Figure%02d.pdf',N ));` it produces N figures Figure1.pdf - FigureN.pdf
`saveas(gca,sprintf('Figure%02d.eps',N ));` it produces N figures Figure1.eps - FigureN.eps

in place of `gca` one can use `gcf` also. First command line is a better solution.

Hope this will solve your issue.