# Plot dots and squares on two images in matlab

Tags: matlab, homography

I know this has been asked before, but I couldn't apply it.

I'm applying homography on an image, and for the report, i need to show which points I did chose (plotting dots), and I need to show also the corresponding square on the proccesed image.

One of the images I used is

[image: http://puu.sh/cmsL1/02c1ef6e64.jpg]

The points I need to plot as dot are

```
 X           Y

 95.0000   109.0000
 80.0000   297.0000
385.0000   274.0000
383.0000   224.0000
```

and the points I need to plot in the image below as a square are

[image: http://puu.sh/cmsQb/45349305cd.jpg]

```
 Xp   Yp

 90   133
 90   198
391   198
391   133
```

Hope you can help me!

I tried

```
p=[3,4]
plot(p(1),p(2),'Marker','p','Color',[.88 .48 0],'MarkerSize',20);
```

But I really don't understand the code. It plots dots on a white image. Later I tried

```
hold figure
imshow(im) plot(p(1),p(2),'Marker','p','Color',[.88 .48 0],'MarkerSize',20);
hold on
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: @Jias I first tried plotting any point, for example
p=[3,4]
and the I used
plot(p(1),p(2),'Marker','p','Color',[.88 .48 0],'MarkerSize',20);

but I really don't understand the code. It plots dots on a white image, and later i tried used 
hold
figure, imshow(im)
plot(p(1),p(2),'Marker','p','Color',[.88 .48 0],'MarkerSize',20);
hold on

but it didn't worked

Comment: Please share the code you've tried. Put it in the question, not a comment. Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first

Comment: Try reading [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/01/01/superimposing-line-plots/).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178336/matlab-how-to-plot-x-y-on-an-image-and-save

Answer (score 0):

To plot the points over your image do:

```
hold on
scatter(X, Y)
```

You can add properties as well, like if you wanted red circles you could do

```
scatter(X, Y, 'ro')
```

The hold on part is important so that it will do the scatterplot over the previous plot you have, which should be your image.

As for the square, the same applies, plot your image, do hold on and use the line command like so

```
hold on
line([Xp],[Yp])
```

where xp and yp are row vectors containing all the points in x and y respectively that you want to draw lines between. Remember to add a line at the end connecting the last point to the first.