# Saving a plot as a PNG in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, time-series

I have a function that is plotting a time series, now I want to save this as an image how can this be done please?

```
function TimeSeriesImages(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l)
x = [a b c d e f g h i j k l];
ts1 = timeseries(x,1:12);
ts1.Name = 'Monthly Count';
ts1.TimeInfo.Units = 'months';
ts1.TimeInfo.Format = 'mmm dd, yy'
ts1.Time=ts1.Time-ts1.Time(1);
plot(ts1)
end
```

Comment: Perhaps related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606768/write-a-figure-to-a-file-automatically-in-matlab).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another way of saving figures in Matlab is handle them with variables and saving them later.

For example:

```
a=bar(...);
b=hist(...);   %some figures
c=plot(...);

saveas(a, 'path\to\file\abc1.png','png');
saveas(b, 'path\to\file\abc2.png','png');
saveas(c, 'path\to\file\abc3.png','png');
```

---

Fragment from the official Matlab help:

***saveas*** - Save figure or Simulink block diagram using specified format

**Syntax**

```
saveas(h,'filename.ext') 
saveas(h,'filename','format')
```

**Description**

saveas(h,'filename.ext') saves the figure or Simulink block diagram with
the handle h to the file filename.ext. The format of the file is determined by the extension, ext. *See Matlab help for more.*

Answer (score 8):

You can use `print` with the `-dpng` flag.

Comment: see  [print in the Matlab Doc](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/print.html) for more.

Comment: This method is slightly better in that you can alter the resolution.

Comment: This also removes the need to give each plot/figure a handle, nice