# Save Matlab figure without plotting it?

Tags: matlab, save, plot, figure

Is there a way of saving a figure plot without actually plotting it?
I mean, let's say I want to save the graph for `plot(1:10, (1:10).^2)`, can I save it without showing it?

I want to make the run time shorter by cutting off the unnecessary plotting of the figures (those will be closed anyway after saving).

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I plot to an image and save result without displaying it, in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963674/how-do-i-plot-to-an-image-and-save-result-without-displaying-it-in-matlab)

Comment: @Jonas: Great, there are good answers there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done:

```
set(gcf,'Visible','off');
plot((1:10),(1:10).^2);
print -dpng c:\chris.png  % or whatever your print command is
```

Answer (score 7):

There is also the `saveas(h,'filename.ext')` function which can save a figure in some formats.