# Save Matlab text without opening figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to work with text function in matlab, and using it as an image as following:

```
text('HorizontalAlignment'  , 'center'  ,...
     'position'             , [.5 .5]   ,...
     'string'               , 'HELLO'   ,...
     'FontName'             , 'Arial'   ,...
     'FontSize'             , 300       ,...
     'BackgroundColor'      , 'w');
axis off;
g=getframe(gca);
image=g.cdata;
close;
```

Opening and closing the figure at each time is really bothering me. I googled and I found [Save Matlab figure without plotting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818469/save-matlab-figure-without-plotting-it) but it did not solve the problem. I tried also `set(gca,'Visible','off');` but it does not work either.

Comment: what about `set(gcf,'Visible','off');`? (Note the `gcf` instead of `gca`)

Comment: First of all you can create the figure already hidden with f=figure('Visible','off'), but getframe will show it anyway because that function is there to make screenshots. The print -dpng 'myfile.png' doesn't open the figure, but creating a file and reloading it is not an elegant solution.

Comment: @ Rody: As I mentioned a link, in that link the soloution proposed is, using set(gcf, 'Visible','off') and it does not work, hence I tried set(gca, 'Visible', 'off') since I have g=getframe(gca);

Answer (score 1):

You should try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10889-savefig) Matlab file exchange function. It saves a figure in whatever format you want and you don't need to show it. Anyway, If your program shows figures periodically and you want to show and close them while running try this different commands also:

```
[commandwindow][2] % Directs the user to command window

close all %closes all figures opened

pause %pauses the run until user presses any key in command window

[movegui][3] %can make a figure be shown where the user sets it (not always in the centre of the screen!)
```

With the four of them you can make an interesting running by opening and closing figures automatically while the programs goes on and the user has already understand or checked the figures. Combining this with the image save function you can build a pretty nice program!

I am sure that there are much more command useful for this but didn't use them by myself yet

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `getframe` and not just [`print`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html?s_tid=doc_ta)?

This code seems to do exactly what you want:

```
fig = figure('Visible', 'off'); % as you know - make the fig invisible
t = text('HorizontalAlignment'  , 'center'  ,...
     'position'             , [.5 .5]   ,...
     'string'               , 'HELLO'   ,...
     'FontName'             , 'Arial'   ,...
     'FontSize'             , 300       ,...
     'BackgroundColor'      , 'w');
axis off;
print(fig,'hello.png','-dpng') % you can chage the settings here to what you need
close(fig)
```