# How can I modify an image without showing it?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, drawing

I have a code that loads an image to a plot, draws a rectangle on it an after this saves the image into a png file:

```
    figure('Visible', 'off');
    imshow(im)
    hold on
    for n=1:size(windowCandidates,1)
        rectangle('Position',[x,y,w,h],'EdgeColor','g','LineWidth',2)
    end
    f=getframe;
    [img_bound,map]=frame2im(f);
    imwrite(img_bound, strcat(directory, 'name.', 'png')); 
    hold off
```

How can I do the same without displaying it in a figure? Just modifying it and saving, I dont want the user to see all this process)

Thanks!

Comment: rectangles are easy enough to rasterize, so you should be able to modify the image matrix and draw on it directly, then save the result to disk. This avoid going through the process of screen-capture with functions like `GETFRAME`. You will probably find similar questions here on SO...

Comment: related question: [Render MATLAB figure in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137628/render-matlab-figure-in-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a figure invisible with:

```
figure('Visible', 'off');
```

And then just write it out as Matlab fig via:

```
saveas(gcf, 'path/to/filename');
```

or using the `print` command to png is this case

```
print('-dpng', 'path/to/filename');
```

Similar question with good answers and explanations else where on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963674/in-matlab-how-do-i-plot-to-an-image-and-save-the-result-without-displaying-it)

**Update**

Thanks to [Steve](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/) for pointing to this undocumented [matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3NMHJ5/?solution=1-3NMHJ5)

```
function so;
close all;
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
hfig = figure('Visible', 'off'), imshow(im, 'Border', 'tight');
for n=1:2
rectangle('Position', [20*n, 20*n, 50, 50], 'EdgeColor', 'g', 'LineWidth', 2)
hold on;
end

F = im2frame(zbuffer_cdata(gcf));
imwrite(F.cdata, 'test.png'); 

%   Function copied from 
%   http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3NMHJ5/?solution=1
%   -3NMHJ5
%
function cdata = zbuffer_cdata(hfig)
    % Get CDATA from hardcopy using zbuffer
    % Need to have PaperPositionMode be auto
    orig_mode = get(hfig, 'PaperPositionMode');
    set(hfig, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
    cdata = hardcopy(hfig, '-Dzbuffer', '-r0');
    % Restore figure to original state
    set(hfig, 'PaperPositionMode', orig_mode);
```

Comment: I've tried it but didn't work. It keeps showing the images in increasing figures. I updated the code on the question.

Comment: The problem is with `getframe` . You can save a figure following the other stackoverflow example I linked through.