# Matlab Plot to image without display and save on a no Java server

Tags: image, matlab, graphics, matrix, plot

For the normal answers to this question, it is provided here: [In MATLAB, how do I plot to an image and save the result without displaying it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963674/in-matlab-how-do-i-plot-to-an-image-and-save-the-result-without-displaying-it)

However, this will not work on a server that does not have Java support. This is the output:

```
>> testScript
??? Error using ==> imshow at 191
IMSHOW requires Java to run.
```

We cannot install Java in this server.

Of course, one of the answers suggest to modify the image directly, then go for imwrite. However, it is too primitive, and at this level, we should already have some sort of function that can draw lines.  What are some of the other available options for drawing directly on the image matrices?