# Save Matlab invisible plot under terminal as an image with same size

Tags: matlab, command-line, save, plot

I am SSH connecting to a Linux server and do some MATLAB programming. I would like to save invisible plot as

```
figH = figure('visible','off') ;  
% Plot something  
% save the plot as an image with same size as the plot   
close(figH) ;
```

`saveas()` and `print()` will change the size of the saved image different than the size of plot. Also for `print()`, all three renderer modes (`-opengl`, `-ZBuffer` and `-painters`) can not be used in terminal emulation mode on the Linux server. `getframe()` doesn't work either.
I wonder how I can solve these problems? 
Thanks and regards!

Comment: are you running an X server at your end?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following sequence of commands to connect and start MATLAB:

```
ssh -x user@server          # disabled X11 forwarding
unset DISPLAY               # unset DISPLAY variable
matlab -nodisplay           # start MATLAB without the desktop
```

then a simple plot to illustrate:

```
figure, close                    # must do this first, otherwise plot is empty
plot(1:10)                       # usual plotting
print file                       # save the figure as file.ps
saveas(gcf, 'file.eps', 'eps2c') # saveas aslo works
exit                             # done
```

I just tried it myself, and it works as expected.

---

**EDIT:**

You can always specify the DPI resolution using `-r<number>`, for example a very high resolution:

```
print -dpdf -r600 file.pdf
```

Note that you can use `-r0` to specify screen resolution.

Also you can turn on *WYSIWYG printing of figures* using the `PaperPositionMode` property:

```
figure, close
plot(1:10)
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto')
print -deps2c -r0 file.eps
exit
```

Comment: The problem is that using saveas() or print() does not preserve the saved image size same as the plot.

Comment: wasn't that already addressed in a previous question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848176/how-not-to-save-non-image-area-in-matlab-image-plot

Comment: The solution provided there is actually not for terminal mode and Matlab invisible plot (I accepted it only based on that it works on X mode and Matlab visible plot). Specifically getframe() will return null even under the way you suggested to connect to the server and run Matlab.

Comment: Thanks Amro! That solves my problem! 
Just curious： （1） what is the purpose of "figure, close", and its difference with "figH = figure('visible','off')"? (2) what's the purpose of "unset DISPLAY", and the combination of "ssh -X" with it?

Comment: 1) this is only to prevent a bug og getting an empty plot in the saved file: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HNG/index.html
2) I used those to show that your are not running in X mode. `ssh -x` (small x!) disables X11 forwarding, and then we clear the DISPLAY environment variable that specifies which device/host to use for graphical ouput. Usually just starting MATLAB with the `-nodisplay` option is sufficient..