# MATLAB:: Drawing a number on a image (Matrix) on MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, photo, photolibrary, matlab-figure

I'm using matlab in order to perform  modifications on an image. 
I have loaded an image on Matlab. (the image may be in different resolutions)
Converted the image to gray scale then converted the image's matrix to double.

I have drawn grid lines  on the image 
(I have posted the code how to do that somewhere here on stack over flow).

My problem is that I may have upon the 1000 squares as a result from girding the image on  the X axis and the Y axis.

I'd like to numbering the squares in that image.

Is there an option of  drawing numbers on Matlab ? 
I'd be glad to receive any information about that (except from being a clicking monkey and writing  0 till 1000 on paint haha... ).

Cheers 
S

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a code example to put text labels on an image in the middle of grids:

```
x = imread('cameraman.tif');
image(x)
axis image
grid on
%# grid domains
xg = 0:50:200;
yg = 0:50:200;
%# label coordinates
[xlbl, ylbl] = meshgrid(xg+25, yg+25);
%# create cell arrays of number labels
lbl = strtrim(cellstr(num2str((1:numel(xlbl))')));
text(xlbl(:), ylbl(:), lbl(:),'color','w',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle');
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to capture the resulting image and store it to disk, you might want to to take a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137628/render-matlab-figure-in-memory).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text.html)

> `text` is the low-level function for creating text graphics objects. Use
>   `text` to place character strings at specified locations.
>
> `text(x,y,'string')` adds the string in quotes to the location specified
>   by the point (`x`,`y`) `x` and `y` must be numbers of class double.