# Make a movie with pcolor without getframe

Tags: matlab, movie

I have a simulation running in MATLAB and I want to make a movie from the frames. There are more than 4000 frames at least 1600x1600 in size. Each frame is a 2D matrix. I can visualize them with `pcolor` and make a movie using `getframe`. But as the size is huge and the simulation is running overnight, I will run into alot of problems with screen savers, etc. Is there any better way to do this in MATLAB? Solutions with other softwares is also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link provided in @Bee answer and some tinkering the problem is solved like this:

```
aviobj=VideoWriter(filename);
open(aviobj);
hFig=figure('Visible','Off');

for loop comes here
    cla

    %All Drawing stuff    

    img = hardcopy(hFig, '-dzbuffer', '-r0');
    writeVideo(aviobj, im2frame(img));
end
close(aviobj)
```

Note that it is using the `VideoWriter` instead of deprecated `avifile` and `addframe` and it does the rendering in memory not on disk so it's reasonably fast.

Answer (score 2):

Right before drawing the picture with `pcolor()`, try creating a figure that is invisible using `h = figure('visible', 'off');` and use `addframe(avi_file, h);` to add a frame to the avi coming from the invisible figure. More detailed discussions can be found at [Render MATLAB figure in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137628/render-matlab-figure-in-memory)

**Update:** it seems that there is no way to get a frame using `getframe()` inside a headless Matlab so options using `VideoWriter` and `movie2avi` will not work. If somebody has been successful with this, please correct me in the comments section.

Comment: Removed this strikethrough part of the answer: <s>You can either start Matlab with `-noFigureWindows` option for your overnight runs, and use `getframe()` the same way you are using now, or</s>