# Matlab - running train function under command line environment

Tags: matlab, command-line, neural-network, headless

I am trying to train a neural network, by using the `train` function. The thing is that I want to do this remotely over the internet by using a SSH connection.

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> nntraintool at 28
NNTRAINTOOL requires Java which is not available
Error in ==> trainbr>train_network at 257
[userStop,userCancel] = nntraintool('check');`
Error in ==> trainbr at 116`
[net,tr] = train_network(net,tr,data,fcns,param);`
Error in ==> network.train at 107`
[net,tr] = feval(net.trainFcn,net,X,T,Xi,Ai,EW,net.trainParam);`
Error in ==> ClassifierScript at 28`
[MFLDefectSNetwork,  tr] = train(MFLDefectSNetwork, TrainingInputSet,
TrainingSTargets);`
```

I think I receive this error because of the training interface which is displayed when you want to perform a neural net training. If so, could you please tell me, how can I turn that visual interface off so that I can run this by using ssh connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can solve this by setting the `trainParam.showWindow` parameter of your [network object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ug/bss324t-1.html) to `false` before calling [`nntraintool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/nntraintool.html). For example, if your network object is stored in the variable `net`, you would do this before you train:

```
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
```

This [MATLAB Newsgroup thread](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/301204) also suggests that you may have to comment out some lines in [`nntraintool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/nntraintool.html), which you can open in the editor with the command `edit nntraintool`.

Comment: it doesn't work... I have tried to edit nntraintool, but it won't open in unix environment, I don't know why...

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Comment: not quite... I just used instead the visual connection for ssh, and I tried running the training by using the visual remote connection and this way it worked...

Comment: @Simon: I posted a possible solution, can you check it (without enabling X11 forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

(*Disclaimer:* the following is untested. I currently only have access to a Windows installation of MATLAB)

Try the following sequence of commands to start MATLAB (note that you should NOT use the [-nojvm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/matlabunix.html#f7-630210) option):

```
# on your machine
ssh -x user@host

# on the host
unset DISPLAY
matlab -nodisplay
```

Once in MATLAB, you can explicitly check that Java is available:

```
>> usejava('jvm')
>> java.lang.String('str')
```

Next, proceed to create and use the neural network (you just have to suppress [training feedback](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/nnet/ug/bss326e-1.html#bss326e-8)):

```
%# load sample dataset
load simpleclass_dataset

%# create and train neural network
net = newpr(simpleclassInputs, simpleclassTargets, 20);
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;          %# no GUI (as @gnovice suggested)
net.trainParam.showCommandLine = true;      %# display in command line
net.trainParam.show = 1;                    %# display every iteration
net = train(net, simpleclassInputs, simpleclassTargets);

%# predict and evaluate performance
simpleclassOutputs = sim(net, simpleclassInputs);
[c,cm] = confusion(simpleclassTargets,simpleclassOutputs)
```

As a side note, even though we disabled all display, we can still plot stuff (although invisible) and export figures to files, as I have shown in [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853259/save-matlab-invisible-plot-under-terminal-as-an-image-with-same-size/1853388#1853388) related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137628/render-matlab-figure-in-memory/4138622#4138622)...