# How to run MATLAB without GUI and get the graphical result?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, command-line, ssh

I wanna run matlab on my VPS. What puzzled me most is that I must run MATLAB without GUI by SSH and get the graphical result. 
When I commanded `matlab -nodisplay -r "func()"` in bash, lots of mistake occurred such as

> "Warning: NEWFF used in an obsolete way. " "Error using ==>
>   nntraintool at 28","trainlm>train_network at 228" ...

How can I deal with these mistakes?

Comment: as others have pointed out, the warning you are seeing is not related to graphics output... Otherwise see this related question for saving figures when running in *-nodisplay* mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853259/save-matlab-invisible-plot-under-terminal-as-an-image-with-same-size

Answer (score 1):

If *'get the graphical result'* refers to a file, you may try the following solution provided by The MathWorks.

[Is it possible to save a figure when MATLAB is running with "-nodisplay" option?](http://www.mathworks.ch/support/solutions/en/data/1-1KY74I/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1KY74I)

Answer (score 1):

The warning you are seeing is not connected to the use of graphics over a VPS. They indicate that your `func()` is calling commands from Neural Network Toolbox in a way that is no longer supported.

Comment: And could you tell me how to call the NNT without graphics by -nodisplay mode ? I do not know the relationship between GUI and NNT when matlab process the  data . can you tell me simplely ?