# Printing a transparent figure in MATLAB's terminal emulation mode

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is it possible? The code below illustrates what I want to do:

```
xdata = [0 1 2];
ydata = [0 1 0];
h = patch(xdata,ydata,'w');
set(h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.2);
print -dpng myfig
```

If I start MATLAB using option `-nodisplay` and run the code above, MATLAB simply gives me a core dump. I think that MATLAB should behave a bit better than crashing without further explanations, but I understand that this is due to the fact that neither the opengl nor the zbuffer renderers are available in terminal emulation mode.

I am getting around this problem by plotting the transparent figures in `.svg` format but this is not an ideal solution for me. My MATLAB scripts are generating HTML reports with many embedded figures and most browsers perform very poorly when rendering pages that contain several (relatively complex) .svg images. So, does anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853259/save-matlab-invisible-plot-under-terminal-as-an-image-with-same-size

Comment: @VictorHugo not really. I have no problems to save/print invisible figures under terminal mode, as long as they do not contain any transparent element. It is the transparency issue what breaks MATLAB, i.e. if you remove the fourth line in my code everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An indirect solution to this problem is to print the transparent figures to a `.svg` file using [plot2svg()](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401), and then use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to convert the `.svg` file to `.png`, `.pdf` or any other format supported by [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). Inkscape offers quite good [command line support](http://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) so you can easily script the whole process from MATLAB. Inkscape is available in Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.