# How to save custom-sized figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Printing a MATLAB plot in exact dimensions on paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600945/printing-a-matlab-plot-in-exact-dimensions-on-paper)
>   [How do I save a plotted image and maintain the original image size in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848176/how-do-i-save-a-plotted-image-and-maintain-the-original-image-size-in-matlab)

I have recently been trying to create a custom-sized graph in MATLAB and save it automatically using the saveas function. In particular, I am having issues saving the files in the size that I create them. Roughly speaking, my code is as follows:

```
mygraph = figure('Position',[1,20,1280,1024]);
% creates a figure positioned 1 px from the left of the screen
% 20 px from the bottom of the screen
% that is 1280 px in length and 1024 px in height

% some code to create graph

saveas(mygraph,'mygraphfilename','emf')
% saves figure as mygraphfilename.emf.
```

So far, my code works fine in that it can create a custom sized graph on my screen, but it seems to save the pictures themselves in a default size. The weird thing is that if I do not use the saveas function and save the figure manually, then the image retains its size.

For clarification purposes, I'm currently saving the graphs as emf, though I'm also open to using jpg/png/bmp if works fine too.

Comment: Saving the figure manually (`save as...`) calls the `print` command for some formats. Using that instead of `saveas` may help.

Comment: also these are related: [Save Matlab invisible plot under terminal as an image with same size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853259/save-matlab-invisible-plot-under-terminal-as-an-image-with-same-size), [How do I save a plotted image and maintain the original image size in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848176/how-do-i-save-a-plotted-image-and-maintain-the-original-image-size-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the following:

```
set(mygraph, 'PaperPositionMode','auto')     %# WYSIWYG
print -dmeta -r0 file.emf
```