# Matlab saving figure with predefined size

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a figure with 2 plots on it. I am trying to save the figure as a png with a longer width.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%First%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
a=figure('Name','First Structure');
load C:\Users\William\workspace\P5\FirstAdd.txt
n=FirstAdd(:,1);
t=FirstAdd(:,2);
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(n,t);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('Time');
title('First Structure''s Add');
grid on

load C:\Users\William\workspace\P5\FirstContains.txt
n=FirstContains(:,1);
t=FirstContains(:,2);
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(n,t);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('Time');
title('First Structure''s Contains');
grid on

rect=[250,250,1080,480];
set(a, 'OuterPosition',rect);
print(a,'-dpng','First Structure.png');
```

In the last 3 lines I set the figure window such that the 2 plots are wide enough. However, when I try to save the figure, the image is its default size in which the plots are squished.

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a MATLAB plot in exact dimensions on paper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600945/printing-a-matlab-plot-in-exact-dimensions-on-paper), [How to save custom-sized figures in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508233/how-to-save-custom-sized-figures-in-matlab-closed)

Answer (score 12):

The `OuterPosition` [figure property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html) only changes where the figure window is on the screen; it doesn't change how it will print.

Matlab uses the `PaperSize`, `PaperUnits`, `PaperPosition` and similar figure properties when "printing" a figure, even when they don't really make sense, such as when producing a bitmap file.  (Settings `PaperUnits` to `pixels` would be logical, but it doesn't work.)

The procedure for getting a particular image size in *pixels* is to set `PaperPosition` to some size in *inches* (or another physical unit) and then specify the desired *resolution* in dots per inch using the `-r` option to `print`:

```
r = 150; % pixels per inch
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 1080 480]/r);
print(gcf,'-dpng',sprintf('-r%d',r), 'bar.png');
```

Some of these peculiarities are discussed in the help for the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html#brneyqn) function.

You could also try the `-r0` option which tells Matlab to use the display resolution.

Answer (score 5):

Following @nibot's example, I wrote the following function:

```
function save_as_png(handle, filename, dpi, width, height);
    set(handle, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 width height] / dpi);
    print(handle, '-dpng', ['-r' num2str(dpi)], filename);
end
```