# Matlab in Linux: fontsize different between eps and fig export

Tags: matlab, plot

I wish to export figures both in eps and tiff (or png) using Matlab. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218697/matlab-saving-figure-with-predefined-size) thread, I can change figure size and resolution conveniently. But now my problem is that the font sizes in my exported eps and tif files are very different.

For example:

1: using 300 dpi resolution to save a tif file:

```
r=300;
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 1024*2 1024*2]/r)
print(gcf,'-dtiff',sprintf('-r%d',r), 'contour.tif');
```

I get a very small font size (same applies when saving to png and jpg)
[image]

2. Perhaps the resolution is affecting the font size. Because when I set r=0 (i.e. resolution the same as the display), the font size is very close to what I want:

   r=300;
   set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 1024*2 1024*2]/r)
   print(gcf,'-dtiff',sprintf('-r%d',0), 'contour.tif');

[image]

But the problem is that such resolutions can not be published as zigzags. This can be seen when slightly zoomed in.

Just wondering how I can set all figure outputs to be consistent between formats, particularly between eps and tiffs, without using third party software (e.g. using Illustrator to export)?

Comment: There are numerous problems getting graphics out of MATLAB correctly. Have you tried export_fig on the File Exchange on The Mathworks website?

Comment: I understood this can be 'handled' by setting paperposition and resolution differently when saving to eps and fig to get exactly the same figure, but I am looking for the equation! I am now trying to use export_fig and will update if great results comes.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please post a fully executable example, for both eps and tiff.

Comment: as @MichaelJ suggests, `export_fig` is the most downloaded File Exchange submission of all times, and there is a reason for that: IT works amazingly to export figures, way way way better than Matlab's inbuilt functions. In shot: You want to export figs? use `export_fig`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this problem is associated with [the missing font in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218979/changing-figure-fonts-in-matlab-has-no-effect). I use the following commands to resolve three machines installing different distros:

for a ubuntu machine, run:

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi
```

for a gentoo machine, run:

```
emerge -av media-fonts/font-adobe-100dpi media-fonts/font-adobe-75dpi liberation-fonts
```

for a centos machine, run:

```
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi
```

I have to reboot the computer to make the configuration in effect.