# Setting graph figure size

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

All I want to do is make the width greater and the height smaller.  I'm just doing raster plots but this question applies to any MATLAB `figure`.  I can manually resize it using the figure directly when it's created but I want the program to spit it out in the right size to start with.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The properties that can be set for a `figure` is referenced [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html#buich1u-1_sep_shared-Position).

You could then use:

```matlab
figure_number = 1;
x      = 0;   % Screen position
y      = 0;   % Screen position
width  = 600; % Width of figure
height = 400; % Height of figure (by default in pixels)

figure(figure_number, 'Position', [x y width height]);
```

Comment: And how can you save the figure with the same dimensions defined by `set`? As `saveas(gcf, file, 'png')` uses default dimensions instead.

Comment: @IstvánZachar see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600945/printing-a-matlab-plot-in-exact-dimensions-on-paper/3601094#3601094

Answer (score 66):

Write it as a **one-liner**:

```
figure('position', [0, 0, 200, 500])  % create new figure with specified size
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 31):

```
 figure (1)
 hFig = figure(1);
 set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
 set(hFig, 'Position', [0 0 xwidth ywidth])
 plot(x,y)
 print -depsc2 correlation.eps;       % for saving in eps, look up options for saving as png or other formats you may need
```

This saves the figure in the dimensions specified

Comment: +1 for the 'PaperPositionMode' it is necessary of you want to 'print' (export) the figure.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a good result with the following sequence (run Matlab twice at the beginning):

```
h = gcf; % Current figure handle
set(h,'Resize','off');
set(h,'PaperPositionMode','manual');
set(h,'PaperPosition',[0 0 9 6]);
set(h,'PaperUnits','centimeters');
set(h,'PaperSize',[9 6]); % IEEE columnwidth = 9cm
set(h,'Position',[0 0 9 6]);
% xpos, ypos must be set
txlabel = text(xpos,ypos,'$$[\mathrm{min}]$$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',9);

% Dump colored encapsulated PostScript
print('-depsc2','-loose', 'signals');
```

Answer (score 0):

**A different approach.**
On the `figure()` call specify properties or modify the figure handle properties after `h = figure()`.

This creates a full screen figure based on normalized units.
`figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])`

The `units` property can be adjusted to inches, centimeters, pixels, etc.

See `figure` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html).