# How do I make a Matlab plot fill the whole page?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to make a plot in Matlab which is twice as tall as it is long. I tried following the advice of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183047/setting-graph-figure-size) using `Position` and `PaperPositionMode`, like so:

```
figure
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
set(gcf, 'Position', [0 0 100 200]);
barh(1:20);
print('test', '-dpng');
```

Annoyingly, this resizes the paper size but not the plot, as below.

[image: a large plot on undersized paper]

Is there any way to make a graph with specified width and height? I'm running this on a headless server so clicking and dragging, or any other GUI-specific solutions, aren't an option. Obviously I don't actually want a 100x200 plot, I just wanted to make the figure small enough to fit nicely into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try setting the paper size and units.  [There's a similar question on Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/16784).  Relevant content:

```
set(0,'defaultfigurepaperunits','inches');
set(0,'defaultfigurepaperorientation','landscape');
set(0,'defaultfigurepapersize',[8.5 11]);
set(0,'defaultfigurepaperposition',[.25 .25 [8.5 11]-0.5]);
```

where `set(0, ...)` sets the root graphics system values.  You could also use your figure instead.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks. It's odd that this isn't the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach reference the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) for `figure()`. Uses the `units` & `outerposition` properties.

```
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
```

See also the `position` property for another approach.