# Matlab equivalent to Python's figsize

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, graph, matlab-figure

In Python's `matplotlib.pyplot` the `figsize` command allows you to determine the figure size, eg.

```
from numpy import linspace, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = linspace(-2,2,100)
y = sin(1.5*x)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('myfigure.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Is there an equivalent command in Matlab that does this? These [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183047/setting-graph-figure-size) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600945/printing-a-matlab-plot-in-exact-dimensions-on-paper/) show different solutions but none are as clean as Python's `figsize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aim for saving/exporting your figure, you must pay attention to the right [Figure Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html), namely:

- [`PaperPosition`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-PaperPosition),
- [`PaperSize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-PaperSize), and
- [`PaperUnits`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1-PaperUnits).

I tested the following code in Octave 5.1.0, but it should be fully MATLAB compatible:

```matlab
x = linspace(-2, 2, 100);
y = sin(1.5 * x);
fig = figure('PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperSize', [8 5], 'PaperPosition', [0 0 8 5]);
plot(x, y);
saveas(fig, 'myfigure_octave.pdf', 'pdf');
```

I created a `myfigure_python.pdf` using your code. Both exported figures have a size of `203.2 x 127,0 mm` which is `8 x 5 inches`, and look quite similar, see the following screenshot. `myfigure_python.pdf` is on the left, `myfigure_octave.pdf` on the right side:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!