# Matlab figure -> Word -> PDF results in bad quality

Tags: matlab, plot, ms-word, figure

I create some figures with matlab and export them by using the "Edit -> Copy Figure" with setting  "Preserve information (metafile if possible)". I import this in Word 2010. However, if I convert the word document with "save as pdf" the figures have artifacts.

The following image gives you an impression. To the left is Word at 400% zoom, to the right is the pdf with 400% zoom. One can clearly see that dotted lines become straight lines etc. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: When you say "import this into Word 2010" - did you do a copy/paste operation? Or did you save the image to disk? Usually you get better results when you do through a file on disk. Microsoft is legendary about breaking their own rules.

Comment: Actually im doing copy and paste at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the comments here to create my own approach (also with help of: [How to set the plot in matlab to a specific size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561999/how-to-set-the-plot-in-matlab-to-a-specific-size)). So here is my function:

```
function figureprint(hFig, width, height, res, filename)

%# figure size printed on paper
set(hFig, 'PaperUnits','centimeters')
set(hFig, 'PaperSize',[width height])
set(hFig, 'PaperPosition',[0 0 width height])
set(hFig, 'PaperOrientation','portrait')

%# export
print(hFig, '-dpng', res, filename)
```

This function is printing a figure to a specific size in cm. E.g.

```
 figureprint(hFig, 12, 10, '-r1500', 'testPng.png')
```

So "hFig" is saved as a *.png with a width of 12cm and a height of 10cm. I measured this and this works fine. Optimizations are of course possible.

If you use

```
set(gca,'LooseInset', get(gca,'TightInset'))
```

the exponent of the multiply factor for the y values is cutted (when big numbers are plotted) (see image). In this cases you have to modify the values, e.g. like this:

```
tight = get(gca,'TightInset');
tight(1,4) = 0.08;
set(gca,'LooseInset',tight)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a bit on the answer that am304 gave - I just tested the following:

```
figure
% create a plot with some fine detail:
plot(sin(1./linspace(0.02, 1, 1000)));
% set the "paper size" of the figure (not the size on screen) to 30x20 cm:
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 30 20]);
% "print" to png with a resolution of 300 dpi
print('-dpng', 'myplot.png', '-r300');
```

This results in the following picture being saved to disk (cropped to show just detail):
[image]

The full size picture is just 43 kB - but it is a very high resolution (300 dpi) rendering so you can see the fine details of the plot.

I can insert this picture into a Word document and save it as a pdf. When I then take a screen shot of the pdf, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see - the detail is pretty much all there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/print.html) function to export your figure to various formats. EPS or TIFF should give good results. I wouldn't use the "Edit -> Copy Figure" if you want high quality figures.

Comment: I can save the figures in good quality, this is not the problem. But But then I do not manage to import them in Word because they are too "big" or too "small". I need a command that exactly saves a figures in high quality for an appropriate size

Comment: You can control the size of the figure you are saving with `print` to whatever you want it to be. See for example "Printing Figures at Screen Size" in the documentation page for the `print` function.

Comment: Definitely good advice not to use copy/paste. I have expanded on your solution, showing the exact steps one might take. With a tip of the hat and an upvote to you...