# Matlab save figure to specific size?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Whe I plot mygraph, it is in the size of [200 200 350 200] (this is what I want), yet the saved graph is not in that resolution but something like 1200X900. May I know what I've done wrong? Thanks!!

```
mygraph = figure('Name', [fileNameNoExtension '_RandStat_Flip_Unknown.eps'], 'Color', 'white', 'Position', [200 200 350 200]);
bar(matrixNoiseLe5(:,8), 'facecolor',[0.1 0.5 0.9]);
set(gca,'FontSize',10); 
axis([0 1400 -0.05 0.05]);
ylabel('\DeltaRS');
xlabel('Noise Index');
saveas(mygraph, [pathstr '\indexes_3E_15L_300_3000I_RandStat_Flip_Unknown.eps']);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a MATLAB plot in exact dimensions on paper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600945/printing-a-matlab-plot-in-exact-dimensions-on-paper)

Comment: SAVEAS is just a helpful wrapper for PRINT function. See the duplicated question above. Figure's `PaperPositionMode` property is the key.

Comment: Thanks Yuk. I've missed the "set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode','auto')". Appreciate!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use MATLAB's `print` function to save a plot to file.

[Hidden away in the docs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/print.html#f30-463492) is this section:

> Printing Figures at Screen Size This example prints a surface plot
>   with interpolated shading. Setting the current figure's (gcf)
>   PaperPositionMode to auto enables you to resize the figure window and
>   print it at the size you see on the screen. See Printing Options and
>   Printing Interpolated Shading with PostScript Drivers for information
>   on the `-zbuffer` and `-r200` options.
>
> `surf(peaks) shading interp set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')`
>   `print('-dpsc2','-zbuffer','-r200')`

This will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Griffin. Actually "set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode','auto')" is exactly what I missed. Appreciate!!