# In matlab how can I save a histogram from command line?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a large number of files that I need to make histograms for therefore I want to save it from the command line. For plots I usually save it in matlab using the following command:

```
figure = plot (x,y)
saveas(figure, output, 'jpg')
```

I want to do the same for histograms:

```
figure = hist(x)
saveas(figure, output, 'jpg')
```

However I get an error that says incorrect handle. I also tried `imwrite` function, the code executes but saves a blank black image. Is there a way in which I will be able to save my histograms?

Comment: does this also happen when using the print command: print(figure,output,'-djpeg')?

Answer (score 13):

When you use [hist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html) with an output argument, it returns the count for each bin, not a handle object like the other types of plots you're used to.

Instead, grab a handle to a figure, use `hist` with no output args to plot into the figure, then save the figure.

```
fh = figure;
hist(x);
saveas(fh, output, 'jpg')
close(fh)
```

Answer (score 1):

`export_fig` from the [MATLAB file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) handles this for you automatically, and has other nice features as well. For an example of how to use it see another answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267928/274967).

Answer (score 0):

```
fh = figure;
imhist(x);
saveas(fh, 'output', 'jpg');
```