# Matlab figure fixed height

Tags: matlab

I have to prepare multiple 2D model plots (imagesc) whith common Y-scale (it's depth in my case). My models differ in lenght (X-axis). I've tried setting daspect(), but then I get figures (i export them to PNG) where plots have proper dasepct but different height in pixels. I can't just resize pngs because that would change size of all annotations. Any idea how to fix height of vertical axis?

For example if one model is 200 km in lenght its image is 20 cm in lenght, then the other model that is 100 km long should have plot 10 cm long, but both should have the same height and annotation sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to play with PaperUnits, PaperPosition and PaperSize options. Probably, the simplest trick would be to use (output resolution 100)

```
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','normalized','PaperPosition',[0 0 1 1])
print -dpng filename.png -r100
```

Other options are shown here [Export Matlab figure as PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261823/export-matlab-figure-as-png)