# How to export a MATLAB plot without changing the color?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to export plots of MATLAB but the colours change a bit.

This is my exportation using RGB and 600 as resolution:

[image]

And this the screenshot:

[image]

I would like to know how can I keep the red of the screenshot one.

Thank you.

Comment: sometime the color of the image will change a little, but maybe you could try 
 `plot(x,y,'Color',[0.9,0,0.3]) ` and change the color of your figure.

Comment: @HunterJiang I'm going to try that way. Cheers.

Comment: I don't see a color difference. Your plot is made with lots of lines, it is possible that the exported figure, having a higher resolution, gives a less dense collection of lines, letting you see more of the background through. Reducing the resolution to that of the screen would solve the issue, but is not what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this framework?
https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Else this problem might be related to the export command [Export Matlab figure as PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261823/export-matlab-figure-as-png)